# split string into several rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with a string which contains several delimited values, e.g. `a;b;c`.

I need to split this string and use its values in a query. For example I have following table:

```
str
a;b;c
b;c;d
a;c;d
```

I need to group by a single value from `str` column to get following result:

```
str count(*)
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   2
```

Is it possible to implement using single select query? I can not create temporary tables to extract values there and query against that temporary table.

Comment: [You'll finder answer here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement)

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej, I have seen that example. It works only if I have one string, but I have many strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment to @PrzemyslawKruglej [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079928/997660)

> Main problem is with internal query with `connect by`, it generates astonishing amount of rows

The amount of rows generated can be reduced with the following approach:

```
/* test table populated with sample data from your question */
SQL> create table t1(str) as(
  2    select 'a;b;c'  from dual union all
  3    select 'b;c;d'  from dual union all
  4    select 'a;c;d'  from dual
  5  );
Table created

--  number of rows generated will solely depend on the most longest 
--  string. 
--  If (say) the longest string contains 3 words (wont count separator `;`)
--  and we have 100 rows in our table, then we will end up with 300 rows 
--  for further processing , no more.
with occurrence(ocr) as( 
  select level 
    from ( select max(regexp_count(str, '[^;]+')) as mx_t
             from t1 ) t
    connect by level <= mx_t 
)
select count(regexp_substr(t1.str, '[^;]+', 1, o.ocr)) as generated_for_3_rows
  from t1
 cross join occurrence o;
```

Result: *For three rows where the longest one is made up of three words, we will generate 9 rows*:

```
GENERATED_FOR_3_ROWS
--------------------
                  9
```

Final query:

```
with occurrence(ocr) as( 
  select level 
    from ( select max(regexp_count(str, '[^;]+')) as mx_t
             from t1 ) t
    connect by level <= mx_t 
)
select res
     , count(res) as cnt
  from (select regexp_substr(t1.str, '[^;]+', 1, o.ocr) as res
          from t1
         cross join occurrence o)
 where res is not null
 group by res
 order by res;
```

Result:

```
RES          CNT
----- ----------
a              2
b              2
c              3
d              2
```

[**SQLFIddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41fae/7)

Find out more about [regexp_count()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions147.htm#SQLRF20014)(11g and up) and [regexp_substr()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) regular expression functions.

**Note:** Regular expression functions relatively expensive to compute, and when it comes to processing a very large amount of data, it might be worth considering to switch to a plain PL/SQL. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787116/oracle-sql-the-insert-query-with-regexp-substr-expression-is-very-long-split/18788096#18788096).

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but seems to work. The problem with the `CONNECT BY` splitting is that it returns duplicate rows. I managed to get rid of them, but you'll have to test it:

```
WITH
  data AS (
    SELECT 'a;b;c' AS val FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'b;c;d' AS val FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'a;c;d' AS val FROM dual
  )
SELECT token, COUNT(1)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT token, lvl, val, p_val
      FROM (
        SELECT
            regexp_substr(val, '[^;]+', 1, level) AS token,
            level AS lvl,
            val,
            NVL(prior val, val) p_val
          FROM data
        CONNECT BY regexp_substr(val, '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
      )
    WHERE val = p_val
  )
GROUP BY token;
```

```
TOKEN                  COUNT(1)
-------------------- ----------
d                             2 
b                             2 
a                             2 
c                             3
```

Comment: This approach works for three rows, that will not work for 100 rows. Main problem is with internal query with `connect by`, it generates astonishing amount of rows and distinction will take lot of time. I ran this query on real data (val contains up to 7 concatenated values) it is 2 mins since it started and it is still running

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Yep, that's the problem with the `CONNECT BY` approach. Would you consider using a stored function which would produce rows and you would use the `TABLE` function to query that function?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME,COUNT(NAME) FROM ( SELECT NAME  FROM ( (SELECT rownum as ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR('a;b;c', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL )  NAME
       FROM dual  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('a;b;c', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL))
       UNION ALL  (SELECT NAME  FROM ( (SELECT rownum as ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR('b;c;d', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL )  NAME
       FROM dual  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('b;c;d', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)))
       UNION ALL 
         (SELECT NAME  FROM ( (SELECT rownum as ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR('a;c;d', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL )  NAME
       FROM dual  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('a;c;d', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)))) GROUP BY NAME

NAME  COUNT(NAME)
----- -----------
d               2
a               2
b               2
c               3
```